# Make text inside header responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

The following header looks fine on full-width; but once I start sizing down; there's a large gap to the left of the ipsom lorem text, where it should be filling in the full-width of the screen as it sized down. (First picture is full-width; second picture is what should happen when it sizes down).
[image]

[image: 2]

Here is my code so far:

```
.header {
    background-color: #090c1a;
}

.header-inner {
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 180px auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(50%, auto);
}
```

I've also created a codepen for convenience. https://codepen.io/tiotolstoy/pen/PoPzoQw

Comment: What exactly do you want it to look like on mobile screens?

Comment: I'd like it to take up the full width instead of having padding to the right as it would with my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a grid is the best approach for what you described. I would do it with a "max-width: 590px" on the nested div inside the header-inner. like here - https://codepen.io/urich/pen/rNOLNZd

```
.header-inner {
  color: white;
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 180px auto;
}

.header-inner >div {
  max-width: 590px;
}
```

Comment: This implementation collapses the left of the text though. The idea is for it to remain proportional as it scales down. And then eventually take up the full-width for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the mobile version's `p` element to take up full width, with just a tiny bit of padding to prevent text from touching the edge, change your CSS to this:

```
.header {
    background-color: #090c1a;
}

.header-inner {
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

You could also add a media query for the larger version to prevent the text from stretching the entire length of the div if you don't want the `p` element spread out too far on large screens, like this:

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .header-inner {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Play around with the percentage until you get the desired width on full screens.